# Programming a Discord bot in Python- Is there a limit to the length of embed field values?

Tags: python, discord.py

Is there a limit to the length of embed field values? Here's my code:

```
@client.command()
async def rules(ctx):
  em=discord.Embed(title=None, color=0xfdcb58)
  em.add_field(name="Server Rules", value="Random really long paragraph of text blah blah blah...")
  await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

It gives me an error: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, but I do not get the error if I shorten the value. Is there a way to get around this?

I'm new to programming, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each embed can have a maximum of 6000 characters. Each field value can only have a maximum number of 1024 characters.

I suggest you split your embed into multiple fields instead of just the one.

Comment: Okay, but when I make a new field, it puts it side-by-side with the other one. How would I make it *below* the other one?

Comment: you add the option `inline=False`